# How to prevent merge of Pull Request containing more than one commit?

Tags: bitbucket

In my company we have the following workflow: development is done on a dev branch, once author wants to merge the changes he/she squashes the changes and create a Pull Request. If during the review turns out the rework is needed then the author adds new commits to the branch. Once everything is approved the author should squash commits and rebase the code (if needed). Then the maintainer merges the branch to the master branch, which results in one commit only to be added (plus the merge commit). This is to keep the log neat.

However occasionally the maintainer overlooks the fact the commits on the dev branch weren't squashed which results in multiple "work in progress" commits to be included in the master branch. We want to avoid the situation. The question is how to do that?

I was looking through Pull Request "merge check" plugins that could e.g. disable "Merge" button if there is more than 1 commit between source and destination branches, but so far I haven't found any.

I know we could enable automatic squashing on merge but we decided not to squash automatically. We feel it's better for us if the squash is done manually by the developer, e.g. commit message may be corrected accordingly.
Correcting the history in the master branch is also not possible due to our policy forbidding rewriting history on that branch.